# Cycle iteration in stylus with rotate and delay

Tags: rotation, spinner, delay, stylus, preloader

I want to create spinner preloader (like ios-style) with **stylus**.

I have `for` cycle in the `petal` element.
My variables `delay` & `degree` are not compiled correctly
I need to rotate every nth-element and delay each animation

Help me please. Here is my code:

```
    animation a-preloader 1s infinite linear
    delay = 0s
    degree = 0deg
    for num in (1..12)
        &:nth-child({num})
            animation-delay delay
            transform rotate(degree)
            delay = delay + 0.083s
            degree = degree + 30deg
```

**[And here is my playground Codepen](http://codepen.io/AliveDD/pen/OXpJpO?editors=0100)**

Expected result:

[image: preloader]

Comment: where is the problem? your example looks fine

Comment: i resolve this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need declare increments

```
delay = delay + 0.083s
degree = degree + 30deg
```

out of `&:nth-child({num})`, like this:

```
animation a-preloader 1s infinite linear
delay = 0s
degree = 0deg
for num in (1..12)
    &:nth-child({num})
        animation-delay delay
        transform rotate(degree)
    delay = delay + 0.083s
    degree = degree + 30deg
```